# Plug-in missing after setting target platform

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-pde, p2, target-platform

I've a really strange problem here with eclipse ... I've defined a target definition within my eclipse and set it to be the active target platform.
After my workspace has been built eclipse complains about that it cannot resolve the bundle `javax.inject` although I can find it in the target platform ...
Here a screenshot from my target platform with the "missing" plug-in:

[image]

The strange thing is now that I also cannot find it in the run configuration as this screenshot clearly shows:

[image]

In my manifest where I've a dependency to this plug-in it also says that the bundle cannot be resolved, but when I double-click on the plug-in it opens and says that the plug-in can be found under the following directory: `\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\plugins`
[image]

I've struggled all day long to solve this problem, but I couldn't find anything out except that this problem seems to occure with eclipse Juno only ... I've installed eclipse Luna and with this version it works well, but our default IDE is Juno so it needs to work with this version as well ... 
I've absolutely no idea what is going wrong here because I always thought the meaning of a target platform is exactly this to resolve such dependencies between different kind of eclipse versions ...

Comment: I suppose that this is a PDE or p2 problem. Adding the respective tags may help to attract people who may know the answer.

Comment: If 100% on the bundles are selected in the target content, the target definition simple stores 'Include All Content'.  If one or more bundles are unchecked, we store a list of the excluded bundles.  You are hitting a bug in the logic, a bug that was corrected in the Kepler release.  Do you have multiple target locations that could provide the bundle?  If so you could be encountering: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404512

Comment: Why can't you just include everything in the target platform?  It's all being downloaded anyways. Unchecking it in the target content tab is just removing/disabling it from the resolver PDE uses.  The best workaround I can think of is to include everything.

Comment: Ok first thanks for the reply ... I've also found out the same behaviour that as soon as you deselect one plug-in the above stated failure occurs, but when you select all it works fine ...
I need to uncheck some of my plug-ins because some of them are singleton and you can only have one singleton active at the same time otherwise I get an exception by eclipse ... 
OK I think we have no other choice than to change our eclipse version to either Kepler or Luna or create our own update site which contains exactly the plug-ins necessary without duplicates ...

Comment: @CWindatt I just realised that we've already talked about that in this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=452152
So I guess we have no other option than to either fix this bug by ourselves or to use a different eclipse version ;)